# Google web cache not visible for angular 5 universal app

Tags: angular, caching, angular-universal

I have this Angular 5 Universal working in production.
I am not able to view full webpage when I try to view web-cache of it. If I inspect the page, I only see header and footer and nothing else inside the body of router outlet. I also have noticed this one thing, where I could see the page for a few moments and then it goes away after split-second.
This is weird, as I can view full page source on actual website but not on the web-cache of it. But when I open source file of the page that got downloaded in the network tab, I can see the whole HTML content.
what could be causing this problem? Is it possible that this issue could result in further SEO indexing problems?

Comment: any solution you found @Atom19